# What does the notation $[V]^2$ mean (in graph theory)?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, graph-theory, notation

In graph theory, a graph is a pair $G=(E,V)$ of sets satisfying $E\subseteq[V]^2$. But what is $[V]^2$?

I suppose that it is the same as $V\times V=V^2$, but I do not know where the square brackets come from.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In set theory (and graph theory, apparently), $[X]^n$ denotes the set of subsets of $X$ that have precisely $n$ elements.

Symbolically: $$[X]^n = \{Y \subseteq X: |Y| = n\}$$

---

In combinatorics, the notation $\dbinom X n$ is also seen for $[X]^n$.

Comment: Another notation for the same thing, sometimes used in combinatorics, is $\dbinom X n$. ${{}\quad{}}$

Comment: So, does it mean that $[X]^2 = (X^2\setminus \Delta)/\sim$ where $\Delta$ is the diagonal and $(x,y)\sim (y,x)$?

Comment: Yes, that's the same. But I wouldn't consider that a more insightful rendition.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I've never seen that used to represent the _set_ of subsets; it seems like it would be easy to confuse with the standard meaning as the count of such subsets?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki : Remember that $X$ is a _set_, not a number, and $n$ is a number.